# How to search for apps only in Windows 7 START BUTTON search?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I'd like to just show apps in the START BUTTON search results

example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI0Vx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, you can use "type:LNK notepad" in search, and this will give you basically a list of links (or windows shortcuts) that have "notepad" in the filename